# After completing the main story line in Torchlight, is there anything more to do?

Tags: torchlight

I completed the main story line pretty early then continued about 20-30 levels down the "new" dungeon and looks like that's about the only thing I can do - which becomes somewhat tedious.

There are three quests in each level, but they're also pretty much the same.

Am I missing something, or is this just the game "epilogue"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you're pretty much done at this point. Once you finish the main story line, you unlock the endless/infinite dungeon. Monsters here keep getting harder and harder the deeper you go. Eventually the quality of the gear you find falls behind the difficulty of the monsters, and it gets *really* hard. Looking for a challenge?

Also, you also now have the ability to "retire" your current character. This deletes the character and lets you create a new successor character. The new character gets a +1 bonus to Fame (1 extra skill point), and gets to keep one piece of equipment from the retired character. This item will [get a boost to its stats](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?p=82017#p82017) (in the neighborhood of 10%), and the level requirement will be slightly reduced.

Comment: Thanks, that's as much as I suspected. Saw about retiring, might be good idea before Torchlight II is coming. :)