# What is there to do after beating Inferno mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I beat Inferno mode on Diablo 3 so I'm trying to figure out what to do next. There are a couple things I know about, like grinding up your paragon level, but that doesn't really appeal to me. I'm hoping someone can list the activities you can do after Inferno mode so I can decide whether to keep playing or move onto something else.

What is there to do besides beating Inferno mode?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not sure about that; it seems to me like "what else is there to do?" can easily be answered from an objective standpoint. See: [After completing the main story line in Torchlight, is there anything more to do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32654/after-completing-the-main-story-line-in-torchlight-is-there-anything-more-to-do).

Comment: @Schism He's not asking what else there is to do; he knows what there is.  He wants someone to provide a goal for him to do, now that he's beaten his current one.  His examples point towards that.

Comment: @fbueckert I've edited the question to fix your concerns.

Comment: For the record, I think that whoever edited this question dramatically changed the tone and meaning of it in the process.  This version is much more subjective than what I had originally typed.

Comment: @JeffGohlke There's a discussion of this question on [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/whats-wrong-with-asking-for-an-equivalent-goal-to-another-game) right now.  Maybe you'd like to participate?

Comment: @Brythan Oh, interesting.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the original question, the closest equivalent to the Pandemonium Event in Diablo 3 is the [Infernal Machine Event](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89282/how-can-i-craft-the-hellfire-ring).  You can of course perform this sequence as many times as you like (just as you can continue to beat Inferno repeatedly).  If you are looking for a new goal though, leveling your character to the point of being able to build a single Hellfire Ring is a reasonable goal.  It's possible to build a Hellfire Ring even on lower Monster Powers, but it's easier on the higher ones ([how many runs to get a Hellfire Ring](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120837/whats-the-expected-value-of-number-of-runs-required-for-a-hellfire-ring)).

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know this existed, and this was the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the things most people do after completing Inferno:

- Grind Paragon levels*
- Farm keys for Infernal Machines to try to get decent [Hellfire Rings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89282/how-can-i-craft-the-hellfire-ring)*
- Farm Demonic Essences to try to craft better gear*
- Farm gear for upgrades or to sell on the Auction House*
- Experiment with unusual builds
- Try different classes
- Try Hardcore mode
- Complete all the [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3+achievements) possible
- Play the Auction House by buying low and selling high
- Play co-op games for both social interaction, and to see how your class compares to, and complements, other classes

*The various types of grinding and farming can all be done at the same time, and devising routes that are the most fun, most varied, or most efficient can add some extra levels of interest to some.

Comment: everything just comes down to, hit paragon 100 and get better gear, which boils down to - better DPS and EHP

Comment: @spartacus Generally, for most people, but that doesn't appeal to everyone.  I know quite a few people who were more interested in achievements than gearing up.  Hardcore mode is basically starting fresh, and even those who are into hard-core leveling and grinding put a lot of work into min-maxxing routes, gear, and builds.

Answer (score -3):

there are a lot of things you can such as farm bosses to get legendary gear as i have done or find people to play with and enter hell rifts and nephilim rifts or just kill the main bosses.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! While this post does answer the question, it's not very informational or well written. I suggest 1) Adding details and options that aren't in the other two answers, or expanding greatly upon what they have and 2) correcting your grammar and capitalization. We hope that you'll stick around and learn the style of the community, but as it stands, this is a very poorly written answer and will likely gain a lot of downvotes.